# Apache JMeter connection error

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

Hi 'm doing load testing with apache testload. am gettimg this error but no stacktrace on my tomcat server

```
   java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPJavaImpl.sample(HTTPJavaImpl.java:479)
        at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:62)
        at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1054)
        at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1043)
        at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:416)
        at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:271)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the URL you've entered cannot be reached - have you:

- Got the correct hostname and port number?
- Checked if there is a firewall between your desktop where you're running JMeter and the Tomcat server?
- Checked to see if you can get to the tomcat instance via a browser?
- Does the browser use any proxy settings that you haven't mirrored in your JMeter config?

Comment: Yes, it's only a certain number of request that I get this error